# Selenium/Python Unable to use `:contains()` in CSS_SELECTOR

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I try to use `:contains` in Selenium's `By.CSS_SELECTOR`, such as

```
presence = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn:contains('Continue Shopping')"))
```

or

```
presence = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn\:contains('Continue Shopping')"))
```

or

```
presence = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn\\:contains('Continue Shopping')"))
```

the Python program crashes with the error

```
Exception: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.54)
```

Is it possible to use `:contains` in Selenium? The CSS selector

```
$('.btn:contains("Continue Shopping")')
```

works fine in Chrome's JS console.

*Using Chrome 95.0.4638.54, ChromeDriver 95.0.4638.54, Python 3.10 on Ubuntu 20.04.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector `:contains('text')` is a [jQuery selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), not a valid C[SS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) like Selenium is expecting. I'm assuming the reason it works on the page via Chrome's DevTools console is because the page has jQuery defined on it.

Unfortunately, I do not believe you can directly select an element via its text using a CSS selector ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)).

You have two options as far as I can see:

1. Alter your selector to be class or ID based (easiest)
2. Create a Selenium utility to run a JS script that uses this jQuery selector; e.g. `execute_script("jQuery(" + id + ":contains('" + text + "')", id, text)`

Comment: Oh... is it possible convert `'.btn:contains("Continue Shopping")'` into an XPath selector? I can't seem to figure it out. If so, we can use `By.XPATH` in Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Aspok your CSS locators are not a valid CSS locators.
To locate element based on it text you can use XPath locator, something like:

```
//*[contains(@class,'btn') and(contains(text(),'Continue Shopping'))]
```

In case `btn` is the only class name attribute of that element your XPath can be

```
//*[@class='btn' and(contains(text(),'Continue Shopping'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @aspok, it is not a valid css selector.

In case you would like to have XPath for the same, and `.btn` is class and have text/partial text

```
Continue Shopping
```

You can try the below  XPath :

```
//*[contains(text(),'Continue Shopping')]
```

or

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Continue Shopping') and contains(@class, 'btn')]
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Continue Shopping') and contains(@class, 'btn')]
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Also, Just letting you know that, `//*` can be replaced by `tag name`, if you found multiple **matching nodes**.